# Removing regex characters from a string using re module

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to remove regex characters from a string.

My string is "${lm://Field/2}", and I'm trying to make the output string to be "Field2" or "Field_2", are there any good ways doing so using the re module?

So far I've tried

```
F2 = "${lm://Field/2}"
f2_sub = re.sub(r'[${}[lm]:[/\]', r'', F2)
print(f2_sub)
```

But it gives me an error that "unterminated character set at position 9"

Also if I have a sentence that contains "${lm://Field/2}" "${lm://Field/3}", "${lm://Field/4}" how may I write a loop to make all of them to be "Field2" "Field3" "Field4"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using `\]` escapes the closing bracket so your opening `[` is not balanced. Maybe try `re.sub(r'[${}:/]|(lm)', r'', F2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use re.findall to extract names that are between `${lm://` and `}`, then replace/remove intermediate slashes:

```
import re
F2 = "${lm://Field/2} ... ${lm://Field/3} ... ${lm://Field/4}"

fields = [s.replace("/","") for s in re.findall(r"\$\{lm://(.+?)\}",F2)]

print(fields)
['Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4']
```

If your final objective is to replace these placeholders with the corresponding values, you can use a dictionary and a lambda function with re.sub:

```
values = {"Field/2":True, "Field/3":"ABCD", "Field/4":46 }

F3 = re.sub(r"\$\{lm://(.+?)\}",lambda m:str(values[m.group(1)]),F2)

print(F3)
# True ... ABCD ... 46
```

Since the placeholders are (mostly) fieldnames enclosed in curly brackets, you could use the  .format() method to do the value substitution by adjusting them a bit beforehand:

```
F2.replace("${lm://","{").format(**values)

'True ... ABCD ... 46'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_data = "${lm://Field2} ... ${lm://Field/3} ... ${lm://Field/4}"
match_list = re.findall(r'Field|[\d]+', str_data)
print(list(zip(match_list[::2],match_list[1::2])))
```